# Set image to UICollectionView Cell on tap

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, didselectrowatindexpath

I am using UICollectionView and i want to show check box when user taps on the cell, i have enabled multi selection also.
I tried to unhide imageView from didSelectItemAtIndexPath, but it's not working properly

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   cell.checkBox.hidden = NO;
   cell.checkBox.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check"];
}
```

i click on one cell and the imageView appears for some other cell.
But on the same tap i am also adding imagename to an NSArray and their items are getting added correctly.

Comment: `cell.checkBox.hidden = NO;` from where `cell` is coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out following

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewdidSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; //typecast the cell to your custom cell
   cell.checkBox.hidden = NO;
   cell.checkBox.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check"];
}
```